# Integrability of the many body problem

Tags: classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In classical canonical perturbation theory of many degrees of freedom we encounter the problem of small divisors when attempting to find a solution for the generating function of the canonical transformation. We conclude that the generating function only has a solution if the frequencies are non-resonant meaning that the determinant of their Jacobian is non-zero.

How does KAM theory extend this with the Diophantine condition. My understanding of the Diophantine condition is that it excludes resonant frequencies, which seems to be exactly the same. The other version is how well a rational number approximates an irrational one. How does this shed more light on the problem?

Further would it be correct to say that KAM theorem does not afford a solution to resonant frequencies? Whilst reading "Analytical Mechanics: An Introduction (Oxford Graduate Texts)" by Fasano et al they seem to conclude the opposite is true, at least from my understanding.

Any help on KAM theory is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I am not an expert in this area.  I'm reviewing unanswered questions.  If your question is still 'live', I wonder if adding more context would help get an answer?  ie What (briefly) does KAM theory say about this?  What is the Diophantine condition? Is it simply exclusion of resonant frequencies, or is that your deduction?  Most importantly, how about quoting from the Fasano text?  Any edit to your question will (I think) bring back to the attention of the PSE community.